# What do I insert in the open holes on a board to screw in an mSATA drive?

Tags: installation, msata

My board came with nothing in the brass trimmed holes. I need to mount an M-2 drive, but there is nothing to screw it into. I cannot remember the name of the insert. The photo shows inserts in the holes. Mine came without any. It is a development board

Orange Pi RK3399

[image: Orange pi Pi RK3399]

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of *standoff screws*?

Comment: Will probably need a photo to know exactly what you're talking about. Is this on a laptop, or desktop? It's possible a lockdown screw on a desktop is only optional, according to some images google found...?

Comment: I added an image for it above. It's when the mini PCI goes

Comment: There is nothing to mount standoff screws into. I need to screw the board directly into the female ? (name) in the hole